Thread Safety Atomic Producer/Consumer
I have an app which utilizes a producer/consumer pattern for processing events (2 threads total).  The main (UI) thread atomically writes to a reference-type field, and my instantiated thread atomically reads the field. Here's the demo code:
public class MyApp
{
    private Thread WorkerThread;        // Thread which processes the events.
    private EventArgs QueuedEvent;      // The latest event registered by the app.
    private EventArgs ProcessedEvent;   // The latest event processed by the worker.

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create and start the thread.
        WorkerThread = new(new ThreadStart(DoWork));
        WorkerThread.Start();

        // Attach event
        [...]
    }

    // Event which is fired from the main thread.
    // The timing of this event is unpredictable; 
    // it could be super fast, never fire, or anything in between.
    private static void OnEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set this as the latest event.
        // It is OK if the previous event is LOST.
        QueuedEvent = e;
    }

    // Main loop for consumer thread.
    private void DoWork()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // Copy QueuedEvent to local variable so it's not overwritten.
            var argsToWorkOn = QueuedEvent;

            // For performance, don't do work if the args haven't changed.
            if (argsToWorkOn != ProcessedEvent)
            {
                // Do expensive work with argsToWorkOn.
                [...]

                // Remember that we already did work with these args.
                ProcessedEvent = argsToWorkOn;
            }
        }
    }
}

The Question
Performance in both threads is the #1 priority here; they must not block each other. Given this is case, what is objectively the most performant way to implement thread safety here? Is it:

Not necessary? Definitely not. Unless I'm mistaken.
Use volatile? This was my initial answer. But after researching for several hours, I truthfully have no idea what to conclude concerning volatile here. I've read arguments for and against volatile, especially with respect to modern architecture.
Use lock? Maybe. The main thread could be blocked every time the worker thread reads the field, which is bad.
Use Interlocked? I don't think it's very applicable here, but I could be wrong.
Use ReaderWriterLockSlim? Haven't actually looked too far into it yet, I just know it exists.
Something else?


As a side note, am I seeing correctly that as long as the argsToWorkOn is equal to the ProcessedEvent, the WorkerThread performs a busy loop?

@TheodorZoulias Yes, that's correct.

What is the expected frequency of the events? And what are the latency requirements? A infinite loop like that will eat an entire CPU core and waste a fair bit of power. This may be counterproductive if there is any risk of exhausting available cores.

The actual loop has a Thread.Sleep(1) which keeps the CPU down from ~12% to about 0.2%, at least on my machine. The event reads input from a hardware device which varies from client to client, which ultimately depends on how fast the device sends information. Could be very infrequently or, the usual case, extremely rapidly. Some users were reporting the app to be sluggish to respond before this implementation.


What is objectively the most performant way to implement thread safety here?

Use the volatile keyword:
private volatile EventArgs QueuedEvent;
private volatile EventArgs ProcessedEvent;

This is the absolute winner regarding the utilization of your CPU, and the absolute performance loser regarding your own time and sanity. You would need months of study, especially study of the source code of the .NET runtime, before the confusion goes away and you have a firm understanding of the guarantees that the volatile gives you in practice. And I say in practice because it could be said that according to the official documentation, the .NET source code itself is incorrect, because it makes assumptions that the documentation doesn't provide.
In short the volatile keyword ensures that the CPU instructions of your code will not be reordered in a way that would allow one thread to see an EventArgs instance in a partially initialized state. It also ensures that the compiler will not emit code that reads the QueuedEvent only once and then never reads it again, subsequently returning always the same cached value. A thread that reads the volatile QueuedEvent field will see a reasonably fresh value of the field, about as fresh as it would be if you were using the lock or Interlocked.

"after doing this months-long study, most likely you'll come to the conclusion that your code in its current state is a pile of poo" - some tough love, there -- but I don't disagree :D I think hinting Carl to put some focus on that tight busy loop (and the getting rid of it) would be fair.

This confirms what I've read about volatile then, which is bittersweet. Some yucky business there! As for the busy loop and "poo" code, I would like to get rid of it since it seems a little overkill, but I don't know what the best replacement would be. Perhaps you could modify your answer that'll point me in the right direction for this case?

@CarlSchmidt the components most commonly used for implementing the producer-consumer pattern are the BlockingCollection<T> and the Channel<T>, the first is synchronous and the second is asynchronous. Both are able to propagate millions of items per second from the producer to the consumer. If you want advice about how to implement a specific producer-consumer scenario, I would suggest to post a new question about it. Questions and answers here are expected to be one-dimensional, and focus on one thing only.
